# use 2Xn matrix entries as indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, mapping

Is it possible to use matrix entries as indices to other matrix ?
for example :

```
A=[1 2 ; 4 5 ; 6 7 ];
```

And I want to reach entries of other matrix using A, without using loops.

```
Othermat(1,2), Othermat(4,5) %...
```

If yes how can I do it ?!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, use `sub2ind`:

```
A = [1 2; 4 5; 6 7];
ind = sub2ind(size(Othermat),A(:,1),A(:,2));
values = Othermat(ind);
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested `sub2ind` is a natural way to generate indices.

Of course it is also not very hard to find the linear index directly:

```
A = [1 2; 4 5; 6 7];
Othermat = magic(7);

Othermat(A(:,1)+(A(:,2)-1)*size(Othermat,1))
```